# Switch from iframe "AJAX" to proper AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

This is legacy code.
I'm working on a project where we're using iframes to simulate AJAX.

Basically, we're using the target attribute to submit the `<form>` in an iframe, resulting in the request not opening a new tab. Also, we echo a `<script></script>` in the response from the PHP, and the result is executed since it populates the iframe.

Here's an example of such `<form>` :

```
<form id="form_to_submit" method="POST" action="ajax/createUser" target="iframe_name">
    <input type="text" name="input_to_send">
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#form_to_submit').submit()">Submit With Onclick!</button>
</form>
```

Nowadays, not only this looks evil, but it has one (perhaps others) huge pitfall. If one request is made through this process, and the client goes somewhere, and then goes back in his browser history, it'll send the request again.

To fix this last problem, there are many solutions. I think the one I prefer the most is to use real AJAX instead of iframes. Now, in theory, I could change every single form in the source code to make it use AJAX, but I know I won't have 1 straight week of work just for this purpose.

I'm looking for a "quick" way to intercept these requests before they're sent to the iframe, and send them with AJAX instead.

So far, I tried to target `<form>` tags which have a `target="iframe_name"` and listen to the `submit` event to then send the request again with a same method/URL/data.

```
$('form[target=iframe_name]').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(event);

        var url = $(this).attr('action'),
        datas = $(this).serialize();

        $.post(url, datas).done(function (response) {
            eval($(response).text());
        });
});
```

But that only works if they're submitted through a real click on a submit button. I'd say 95% of these cases are submitted through `onclick` tags which will `.submit()` the forms, and in these cases, the `submit` event won't trigger it appears.

I'm stuck, any idea ?

*Note : I'm tagging jquery only to let you know it's available to be used, even though the question is still relevant with any lib/framework of JS.*

Comment: So you have explained what you wish to achieve, you have explained what you have tried.. where is the source code for your attempt(s)? What appears to be the problem with your attempt(s)....

Comment: I explained that in the question, my code does not work because most ```<form>``` tags are submitted through an ```onclick``` attribute, which won't trigger the ```submit``` event. I tried listening to that event.

Comment: Have you tried using `onsubmit="myfunction()"` or  create an event listener via javascript to listen for `submit`...?

Comment: If I could change every single ```<form>``` tags, I would simply use binding  without HTML attributes, but I can't because there are too many of them. I tried creating an event listener via JS to listen for ```submit```, that's also what I explained ! I'll post the code.

Comment: Posting the relevant source code is always helpful as it gives people something to work with. Without seeing your attempt it's hard to see why the source code is failing which makes it even harder to offer you a solution. Thank you for updating your question.

Comment: Can you show an example of the form that has the `onclick` inline?

Comment: @Rasclatt added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove the `onclick` attributes just by doing a general jQuery action on document ready:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getButton   =   $('form').find('button');
    getButton.prop('onclick',null);

    // put listener script here for new form submit (using ajax)...
});
</script>
```

This piece of code just does a general lookup on the page for all forms, finds the buttons, then removes the `onclick` attribute. Once you do this the form should not submit anymore with that inline javascript.

*I would suggest this be temporary as you incrementally change the forms over time to natively work using the jQuery listener (like the other 5% of forms you have created with no `onclick`)*.